# Retrieve 5 most commented posts in seven last day

Tags: php, laravel

I have articles with comments. I would like to post 5 popular items on my home page based on reviews received over a 7 day period. I tried this :

```
$popularArticles = Article::published()
->whereHas('comments')
->withCount('comments')
->where('created_at', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subWeek())
->orderBy('comments_count', 'DESC')
->take(5)
->get();
```

But with this method, articles that were created more than 7 days ago are "ignored". What I would like is that it is the comments of the last 7 days that define whether an article is popular or not.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter counted comments like this:

```
$popularArticles = Article::published()
    ->has('comments')
    ->withCount(['comments' => function ($q) {
        $q->where('created_at', '>', Carbon\Carbon::now()->subWeek());
    }])
    ->latest('comments_count')
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```